# Correct way of determening the template type of variable in C++

Tags: c++, rtti

Consider the following:

```
class fooBase{
public:
       enum dataType {fooInt, fooFloat, fooInvalid};
       fooBase(){}

       /* void getLocation .. setLocation .. */

       virtual dataType getDataType() = 0;

private:
       int fooDataLocation;
};

template <typename T> class fooDataPoint : public fooBase{
public:
       fooDataPoint(T foodat) :
       fooData(foodat){}

       dataType getDataType(){
                if(typeid(float) == typeid(T))
                return fooFloat;
                if(typeid(int) == typeid(T))
                return fooInt
                return fooInvalid;
       }


private:
        T fooData;
};

template <typename T> class calculatableFooDataPoint : public fooBase{
public:
       fooDataPoint(T foodat, T bardat) :
       fooData(foodat){}

       dataType getDataType(){
                if(typeid(float) == typeid(T))
                return fooFloat;
                if(typeid(int) == typeid(T))
                return fooInt
                return fooInvalid;
       }

       void doCalculation(){
                foodata *= barData;
       }

       /* .. getData .. */
private:
        T fooData;
        T barData;
};

std::vector<foobase *> fooVector;
```

This will enable me to store different types of data in the vector. Then when I need to cast, instead of going through an endless list of `dynamic_case<class<type> *>(pointer)` I could just first check the datatype and then just cast to the correct class type.

Also when serializing and deserializing the datapoints (I just need to save the structure, not the actual data that has been processed),  I could just use the getDataType to determine the type and write the serialized form of it.

I guess my bottom line is, is using typeid(type) for comparision a bad idea, and why?

Secondly, is there a design model that could cover a case like this?

Comment: You could consider using a *variant* type (check boost::variant), that instead of using inheritance and some form of type-erasure implements a discriminated union. Other than that, if you want to pursue this path, you don't need to check all typecasts, the type of `T` is known at compile time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess my bottom line is, is using typeid(type) for comparision a bad idea, and why?

In this case I believe it is. The type of `T` is known at compile time, so there is no reason to go through a sequence of `if`s to determine what you already know. You could write a simple metafunction for that. Also, there is no need to use dynamic dispatch to determine the type of the function, you could store the value in the base:

```
class fooBase {
    enum dataType { fooInt, fooFloat, … };
    const dataType type;
    fooBase(dataType t) : type(t) {}
    …
    dataType getDataType() const { return type; }
};

template <typename T>
struct DataType;
template <> struct DataType<int>   
   { static const dataType value = fooBase::fooInt; };
template <> struct DataType<float> 
   { static const dataType value = fooBase::fooFloat; };
```

Then the constructor of the `dataPoint` would be:

```
template <typename T>
fooDataPoint<T>::fooDataPoint(T data) 
: fooBase(DataType<T>::value) 
, fooData(data)
{}
```

Other than that, the design is not really that good for extensibility, as the base needs to be updated for any type `T` that you might ever want to include (extend the enumeration), but if the set is known in advance that might not be too much of a burden.

If the number of options is limited, *and* the sizes of the objects are not too disparate, you could use a prebuilt solution like `boost::variant`, that has the advantage that it does not require dynamic allocations and it does not force an hierarchy.  The potential disadvantage is that, being a discriminated union, the size of each object is approximately the size (`sizeof`) of the largest type that it holds.

Comment: Just one more question. When I need to handle a calculatableFooDataPoint<type> of FooDataPoint<type>, what is the correct way to cast so that the data type is correct?

As in fooDataPoint<type> * dp = dynamic_cast<foodDataPoint<type>*>fooVector.at(n);

Comment: @Raipe: If you use a discriminated union and you *know* the type, you can use `static_cast` (you will also need `static_cast` if there are no virtual functions). If the type is polymorphic (has at least one virtual function or base), then you can also use `dynamic_cast` or if you *know* (again) the exact type, you can check the equality of `typeid`'s and use `static_cast`.